# Problems recording my 2d game made with Unity (laggy / stuttering)

Tags: unity-game-engine, frame-rate, lag, 2d-games, recording

I'm pretty new to Unity and have a problem. I programmed a small 2D game in Unity that works fine, runs smoothly and doesn't lag at 60 fps. The problem occurs when I try to record a video of my game. No matter which screen recorder I tried (on Windows 10 with Xbox recorder as well as on Android Samsung Galaxy S8 and S5 with different recorders), the video doesn't run smoothly (seems stuttering). I have already tried different quality settings, different fps and switched off vSync, but nothing helped. When I set my game below 60 FPS, the game starts to stutter itself and the FPS is not kept constant. The screen resolution is 1920 x 1080.

I am now very desperate and frustrated about this problem, because I would like to make good quality videos of the game. So if anyone has any idea or suggestions how to solve this problem I would be very thankful!

Comment: Did you monitor how many resources does your game use?

Comment: Yes I looked at the Unity Profiler. I didn`t find anything unusual here, but as said, I am quite new to Unity. So I made some screenshots (links below) of the profiler, maybe you notice something unusual. 
I appreciate the help.

https://ibb.co/dwc4sU
https://ibb.co/geCtmp
https://ibb.co/ek02e9
https://ibb.co/iFKCwp

Answer (score 0):

try this [link](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/video-capture-75653)

it will take you VideoCapture, a free asset made for exactly your purposes. since its free you can add it right to your packages and start using it without trouble, and it elemenates the pesky problem of third party recordings.